# How let cmd output less info

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file, for example: `test.bat`, there is only one command in it:

```
echo Hello
```

Then I run it:

```
D:\cmd\test.bat
```

Then it outputs the result:

```
 //output begin
                     -- This is a blank line, I don't want this
 D:\cmd\echo Hello   -- This is not what I want
 Hello               -- I only want to print this line
                     -- This is a blank line, I don't want neither.
 //output end
```

I only want to print the output of  commands run in the batch file, here is the `echo` command.

But, there are two blank lines, one is at the head of the result, and the other one is at the end of the result. And the `D:\cmd\echo Hello` in the result is neither not what i want.

What should I do?  Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put

```
@echo off
```

in the first line of your batch file. This will prevent output of the command's invocation when they are run (as does prepending a command with @), so it eliminates all the lines that bother you.

Taken from http://ss64.com/nt/echo.html

```
Type ECHO without parameters to display the current echo setting (ON or OFF).

In most batch files you will want ECHO OFF, turning it ON can be useful when 
debugging a problematic batch script.

In a batch file, the @ symbol is the same as ECHO OFF applied to the current line only.

Normally a command is executed and takes effect from the next line onwards, @ 
is a rare example of a command that takes effect immediately.
```

Comment: Well, if you overwrite it all again it's moot, though ;)

Comment: My bad, I think that I was just editing at the exact same time as you, if you like you can re-add them, or I can go back and add them.

Comment: Thanks! The last empty line seems can no be removed. Does the `cmd.exe` auto append a blank line when it flush the output?

Comment: This will get rid of most of the lines you don't want, @srain.  The last blank line is "just the way it works" with DOS (if you have an empty .bat-file with no commands, it will still emit a blank line).  If you want to get rid of it, you'll have to use something other than DOS (AFAIK).